# How to isolate a subnetwork from a graph, including nodes and edges up to depth n?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to write a script which will let me mangle (edit, cut, change) some big network files from a command line interface. One of the things I'm trying to do is isolate a subnetwork from a larger network based on searching for matches in node labels.

So basically I'd have a networkx graph with maybe 7000 nodes and corresponding edges with various labels. Then I'd match a string, eg "Smith" to the nodes. I'd get a match of maybe 30 nodes (label:"John Smith", label:"Peter Smith", etc). I'd then like to make a new networkx network containing those 30 nodes, and the edges they have, and the nodes those edges connect to, up to a depth of n, or optionally until all the nodes and edges are found.

My current code is rubbish, so maybe I'll try to write some pseudocode:

```
for node in networkx_network: 
    if searched_string in node:
        new_network.add(node.subnetwork(depth=n))
```

I've spent days googling for a solution, and maybe subgraph, or neighbors, or connected_components is the right thing to do, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it.

Comment: For your original set of nodes you can use Graph.subgraph(nodes) to get a node-induced subgraph (includes edges between the nodes).  For the additional nodes within n hops of that set which edges do you want?

Comment: I'd like to get all the nodes that link from the nodes in the subgraph, up to N hops. So for the third hop for example, I'd basically get "anyone (any node) who's thrice removed from anyone (any node) named Smith".

Comment: OK - but which edges.  Say you have a triangle and start at one corner and go out 1 hop.  Do you want all three edges or just two?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. All three edges is what I'm after, because I'm trying to map paths of possible influence in a social network. But now that you mentioned it, I'd be interested in the two-edge solution as well, because it seems to me like that would better describe direct influence by the first node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`single_source_shortest_path` has an optional cutoff argument.  Including it you can tell networkx to basically find paths to nodes within a certain distance of a given node.  It's a bit of overkill because there's a lot of other information in those paths you don't need.  If you then just take the keys of the resulting set of paths, you have all nodes reachable within that distance, and networkx has ways to find the graphs containing all of these nodes and the edges between them.

By looking at the source code for this, and removing the effort taken to track the actual paths, you can make it much more efficient if needed.  But as it stands, the following works:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100000,0.00002) #sample graph.
base = range(3) #arbitrarily choose to start from nodes 0, 1, and 2
depth = 3  #look for those within length 3.
foundset = {key for source in base for key in nx.single_source_shortest_path(G,source,cutoff=depth).keys()}
H=G.subgraph(foundset)
nx.draw_networkx(H)
import pylab as py
py.savefig('tmp.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try snowball sampling?
so for the set of nodes you have searched that contains your keyword.
look for all their neighbors, add then to the set.
look for all the neighbors' neighbors, add the new ones to the set.
iterate this process for n times.
at the end you will get a set of all the nodes you want, then use the subgraph function to get a subgraph of all the nodes in your final set.
this may not be the most efficient solution but should work.